# Adding (external) javascript to a theme

Tags: theming, javascript, 8

I'm trying to add external JavaScript to my Drupal 8 theme. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? This function is in my MYTHEME.theme file:

```
      function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      $vars['ext_js'] = array(
        '#attached' => array(
          'data' => 'http://cdn.somelibrary.com/library/2.3.1/js/jslibrary.min.js', 
          'options' => array(
            'preprocess' => TRUE,
            'every_page' => TRUE, 
            'group' => 'NONE',
            ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Then in the theme I'm rendering it with:

```
{{ ext_js }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `'type' => 'external'`, to the `options` array index.
By default, the type is considered to be a reference to a file hosted on your Drupal site; by using `'type' => 'external'`, you are specifying that `data` is a reference to a file hosted on a different host.

Comment: @Bala actually, `'type' => 'external'` may be all that is required to resolve the issue. The default `'type'` is `'file'` for more info see [_drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/_drupal_add_js/8) > 'type'

Comment: I agree this is enough, may be you can add the following to avoid for VLQ, actually someone triggered it for VLQ,   [Add external JavaScript ('external'): Allows the inclusion of external JavaScript files that are not hosted on the local server. Note that these external JavaScript references do not get aggregated when preprocessing is on.]

Comment: I wrote the initial answer from my mobile, perhaps was a little concise. Will endeavour to elaborate next time!

Comment: @Bala I am sorry I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @Compustretch before this answer was in very low quality review queue, now this answer is good enough. try as david suggested to solve your issue. ignore my comments, its only about vlq.

Comment: So it's ok to use 'group' => 'NONE' ?

Comment: @Compustretch Just leave out 'group' and 'preprocess' from the options array.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I find is to just so something like this in your theme .libraries.yml:

```
name_of_library:
  js:
    base:
      'https://path.com/to/js.js': { external: true }
```

Then call it using your .info or .theme file.

Answer (score 1):

This is no Drupal 7, some things have changed, the easiest way to add an external library tested on my local is the following:

locate your MYTHEME.libraries.yml

here you are declaring the new library, change the values for yours.

add the following lines to the file:

```
bootstrap:
  version: 1.0
  header: true
    js:
      https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
```

Spacing is really important.

Then simply call the library from you twig template file:
example:

```
{{ attach_library('MYTHEME/bootstrap') }}
```

don't forget to cache:rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [*Inline JavaScript*](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195#inlinejs) mentioned in Drupal Community Documentation about how to Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a **Drupal 8 theme**, you can put it in either a custom block or even directly in a **Twig template**.

Take a look on [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2358785) on how to locate the current twig filename, say your twig file is.:  [DRUPAL8_ROOT_FOLDER]/themes/[THEME_NAME]/templates/html.html.twig
then modify the html as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES" />
    <script scr="PUT-YOUR-EXTERNAL-SCRIPT_URL-HERE"></script>
  </head>
  <body{{ attributes }}>
    <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable">
      {{ 'Skip to main content'|t }}
    </a>
    {{ page_top }}
    {{ page }}
    {{ page_bottom }}
    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

I've put an external script for sharing button on the twig file in my theme. Then [Install Drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) to *[rebuild](http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/cache/cache-rebuild/)* the cache using `drush cache-rebuild`. Seems it works. You may check it on [*my drupal site*](http://forum.tophyips.info/).